# How long do I need to survive on the rocket skis?

Tags: hyperbolica

In the Frosted Fields there is an inventor who created a pair of rocket skis. They ask you to prove the rocket skis are safe by testing them and surviving until they run out of fuel.

How long do I need to survive on the rocket skis before they run out of fuel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to survive 30 seconds before the Rocket Skis begin to slow down. They will fully stop after a few more seconds.

Source: Hyperbolica Playthrough by 99TH VR. (1:43:31 - 1:44:07)